# Is there a way to mix native code screens and Xamarin screens

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a very important library written in swift with 3D rendering model on scenekit. So is there a way to mix native code screens and Xamarin screens without the need to go through the binding path? Meaning, I want to keep my app on xamarin as is, but I want to add some screens in pure native swift code.

Comment: You would need to bind it as a Swift-based framework https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76 For me, converting Swift to C# is way to go (but of course there is development time issue in the conversion process depending upon how much you understand Swift and C#)

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to mix native code screens and Xamarin screens
>   without the need to go through the binding path?

Short answer is no, you cannot.

When you have swift code and need to use it with xamarin apps you have only two ways.

1. Binding way as you mentioned
2. Rewrite you library from swift to c#.